# Jboss Issue when Running server in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I am trying to configure a local JBoss instance in Eclipse on Mac

Every time i try to run the server I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.jboss.as.server.Main.main(Main.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:272)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:313)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The LogManager was not properly installed (you must set the "java.util.logging.manager" system property to "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager")
    at org.jboss.logmanager.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:60)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.log4j.BridgeRepositorySelector.<clinit>(BridgeRepositorySelector.java:42)
    ... 7 more
```

I am not entirely sure how to solve this so was hoping someone could help.

Thanks

Comment: I assume you have seen this thread? - https://community.jboss.org/thread/195016?tstart=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer from [here](http://community.jboss.org/thread/195016?tstart=0)

> Open the launch configuration for the server definition. Add:
>   -logmodule org.jboss.logmanager to the program arguments before org.jboss.as.standalone

Answer (score 0):

to open the launch configuration double click on the server and click "Open launch configuration" [image]

[image]